# Sitecore Fast Query not returning never published item

Tags: sitecore-query

I have a people node which consists of **3500** people. Out of 3500 people **2600** items are marked as `NeverPublished=True`. So in Web database I have only **900** items.
i want a fast query on master database which return all the items whether published or not published.

I used the following fast query

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Home/People//*[@@templateid='{AECD90BE-9289-4F7F-AA26-6C5ED88B6E65}']
```

When I am executing this fast query in Sitecore XPath window, it is returning 3500 item.

But when I am executing the same query from C# code, it is only returning 900 item. 
I have checked the max item setting, it is set to 0 i.e. no limit on result count

I have checked the Context Database, it is master. I have hard coded the database to master, then again getting same response.

I tried using the SQL Table approach, i.e getting all item id from SQL Table then using sitecore api fetching each item. This time again, sitecore api is returning null for NonPublishble Item.

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: I bet the C# code has Factory.Database set to web

Comment: I bet is Sitecore.Context.Database :)

Comment: I have checked the Context Database, it is master. I have hard coded the database to master, then again getting same response.

Comment: I have faced the similar issue. But still didn't get any clue about it.

Comment: @RakeshBhatt i will update you once I find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing your query against the master database:

```
var database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var items = database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/Home/People//*[@@templateid='{AECD90BE-9289-4F7F-AA26-6C5ED88B6E65}']");
```

Comment: Allow me to nitpick - your code is not setting the context database :)

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko i have updated the answer to be more precise

Comment: I have checked the Context Database, it is master. I have hard coded the database to master, then again getting same response.

Comment: @NitishSrivastava have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411912/querying-sitecore-database-in-code-sometimes-doesnt-return-anything


also, my suggestion on troubleshooting: 1) can you try executing the `database.GetItem({unpublished item id})` in the same place in your code to verify if that returns an item, 2) do you use security disabler?

Comment: @AndreyBobrov Yes I have used Security Disabler because i wanted to change value in some fields of the item. I also tried using database.GetItem with Unpublished Item id but again got null.

Comment: @NitishSrivastava this means that something might be changing context database later on, did you debug and step in?

Comment: @AndreyBobrov yes I have debugged the code. I have also checked the connection string. Can you try this at your end. I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

Comment: @NitishSrivastava did you ever get to the bottom of this? we have the same issue

Comment: @DavidMasters we havtn found solution for this, We have changed our approach for the problem

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same problem. Using a **normal query** solved it. (Just deleting the "fast:"-part from the string.) Off course this has a performance impact, but since we can cache the result of the problem-query, it's not a big issue.